# Как правильно работать с компонентами в Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, livewire, tailwindcss

можете подсказать как правильно работать с компонентами в Laravel 8?
делать обычные vue компоненты или есть еще какой-то способ делать приложение на компоненты?

кажется в 8 версии появилось что-то новое по этому вопросу

дело в том что в новом приложение планируется довольно много компонентов, и много страниц
до этого работал с nuxt, а Laravel использовал только для API, поэтому не знаю как правильно проектировать структуру компонентов используя blade

возможно есть какие-то готовые шаблоны...

UI библиотека будет использоваться TailwindCSS

Comment: Если планируется умный фронт на vue/react/angular/svelte, то не стоит делать кашу из blade компонентов, а использовать его как api

Comment: Еще как вариант, в шаблоне blade указывать только root элемент для Vue, а весь фронт писать в js. Такой вариант имеет смысл, если не весь frontend нужно писать на фреймворке.